# String is Nullable returns false

Tags: c#, .net

Why does:

```
 string s = "";
 bool sCanBeNull = (s is Nullable);
 s = null;
```

`sCanBeNull` equate to false?

I'm writing a code generator and need to ensure every type passed to it is nullable, if it isn't already.

```
       //Get the underlying type:
       var type = field.FieldValueType;

        //Now make sure type is nullable:
        if (type.IsValueType) 
        {
            var nullableType = typeof (Nullable<>).MakeGenericType(type);
            return nullableType.FullName;
        }
        else
        {
            return type.FullName;
        }
```

Do I need to have to explicitly check for a string or am I missing something?

Comment: Does (s is Nullable<string>); return false?

Comment: There's no such thing as `Nullable<string>`. `Nullable<T>` is for nullable **value types**. string is a reference type. And `Nullable` is a static class

Comment: Doesn't the second piece of code work? I think it should. You need to account for the fact that type might be a nullable type, though.

Comment: Yep, the second piece of code was working but I couldn't understand what was going on. Much clearer now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`is` tells you whether a value is of a particular type, or one derived from that particular type.

`Nullable` is a generic `struct` that allows for nullable versions of non-nullable values.

`string` is not a `Nullable`

To tell if a type can have `null` values use the fact that for all such types the default value is `null`, while for all other types it is not:

```
default(string) == null; // true
```

Comment: No, `Nullable` is not the same as `Nullable<>`. The former is a ___static___ non-generic `class`, and the latter is a generic `struct`. When the asker goes `is Nullable`, he is checking against a static class, and nothing can be an instance of a static class, so this is meaningless. Under the new Roslyn-based C# 6.0 compiler of Visual Studio 2015, if compiled with "feature strict", the compile-time error _Error CS7023 The second operand of an 'is' or 'as' operator may not be static type 'Nullable'_ is emitted. On the other hand, using `is` with `Nullable<>` has a special interpretation.

Comment: Example of the latter: `object o = 42; /* ... */ var b = o is int?;` is allowed, and `b` will be `true`. This choice was made by the C# designers because of the very special boxing rules of `Nullable<>`.

Answer (score 3):

`string` is a reference type so it is not `Nullable` as that is reserved for value types.

In fact:

```
var nullable = new Nullable<string>();
```

Gives a compile time error.

> The type 'string' must be a non-nullable value type in order to use it as parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'System.Nullable'

Answer (score 1):

The rational behind `System.Nullable` is to be able to represent undefined *Value Types* using the `null` keyword. It does not mean that you can check whether some variable can be set to `null` using `someVar is Nullable`.

If at compile-time you cannot know beforehand whether some variable would be a value-type or a reference-type, you can use:

```
!someVar.GetType().IsValueType
```

But usually a generic argument would be a better approach.

Answer (score 0):

`Nullable` is just a normal `class` like `MyClass` or `System.String` (`Nullable<T>` is struct though).

So if you type:

```
class _Nullable {}

struct _Nullable<T> {}

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
       string a = "";
       Console.Write(a is _Nullable);
    }
}
```

You wouldn't be surprised if it returns `false` right ?

If you want to check if something is nullable or not you can use `if(!(a is ValueType))`

```
       string a = "";
       Console.Write("a is nullable = {0}", !(a is ValueType));
```

Output : `a is nullable = true`